# plsql for inserting a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare

dno number(4);
dname varchar2(5);
ddate date;
dbasic number(10);
djob varchar2(15);
dcomm number(5);
dept  number(5);
dmgr  number(5);

begin
select empno,ename,hiredate,sal,job1,comm,deptno,mgr
into dno,dname,ddate,dbasic,djob,dcomm,dept,dmgr
from emp
where empno=&userno;
if sql%rowcount>0
then
   insert into newempl
   values(dno,dname,djob,dmgr,ddate,dbasic,dcomm,dept);
   dbms_output.put_line('records inserted into it');
   dbms_output.put_line(dno||' '||dname||' '||ddate||' '||dbasic);
   end if;
   end;
```

Error report:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at line 19
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

I do not understand what the error is.

Comment: line 19 starts from "insert into newempl"

Comment: Why use PL/SQL for this? You can do this completely with a single SQL statement.

Comment: its my assignment question and i am beginner of pl/sql

Comment: I will never understand why teachers use examples of inefficient SQL to teach stored procedures. Probably they are just too lazy to think of proper use cases for stored procedure that actually make sense

Comment: actually the question is in employee table the employees who are managers must be inserted into new table

Comment: I understand that, but it can still be done without PL/SQL

Comment: it can be done but what the error in that can u tell me pls a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: what's the table structure like?

Comment: create table newemp1dno number(4),
dname varchar2(5),
ddate date,
dbasic number(10),
djob varchar2(15),
dcomm number(5),
dept  number(5),
dmgr  number(5),)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it looks like you're inserting values into the wrong columns. Without seeing your table structure (from `describe newmpl` for example) this is a bit of a guess, but this statement:

```
insert into newempl
values(dno,dname,djob,dmgr,ddate,dbasic,dcomm,dept);
```

... is assuming that the columns in the `newempl` table are in a certain order, which may not be (and appears to not be) the case. More specifically here, I think it's complaining about `hiredate`, as you're implicitly putting the `djob` value in that column - assuming the new table looks like `emp` - and the `djob` value can't be converted into a date.

**Update based on comment**: from how you said you created the table, this is equivalent to:

```
insert into newempl(dno, dname, ddate, dbasic, djob, dcomm, dept, dmgr)
values(dno,dname,djob,dmgr,ddate,dbasic,dcomm,dept);
```

... so as you can see when it's laid out like that the columns are not aligned, and you are indeed trying to put your `djob` value into the `ddate` column, which won't work.

It is always safer to explicitly specify the columns, both to prevent problems with different ordering in different environments (though that shouldn't really happen with controlled code) and to prevent this breaking if a new column is added. Something like:

```
insert into newempl(empno,ename,jon1,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno)
values(dno,dname,djob,dmgr,ddate,dbasic,dcomm,dept);
```

As an aside, when declaring your local variables you could specify them [based on the table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#sthref87), for example `dno emp.empno%TYPE`. And as another aside based on your comment, I'd recommend giving local variables different names to the table columns to avoid confusion.

As a_horse_with_no_name said, this can be done with a simple SQL insert, and even within a PL/SQL block it doesn't need separate `select` and `insert` statements; you could just do:

```
insert into newempl(empno,ename,jon1,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno)
select empno,ename,jon1,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno
from emp
where empno=&userno;
```

Unfortunately none of this addresses the requirement that 'the employees who are managers must be inserted into new table', since you aren't doing anything with the `mgr` column. I don't think it would be constructive to do that part of the task for you at this point though, and I'm not sure where `&userno` fits in to that.

Comment: i created table like this                                      create table newemp1                                             (dno number(4),
dname varchar2(5),
ddate date,
dbasic number(10),
djob varchar2(15),
dcomm number(5),
dept  number(5),
dmgr  number(5))

Comment: @user1814884 - updated to reflect your columns names, but this is basically right *8-)

Comment: i am just checking whether  the ans is correct or not, i mean i did not implement actual query (i.e all mgr into the table) i am sorry for not mention explicitly